# jquery stops insert into database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

i have made this script but then i press submit the jquery animation start but it will not submit it into the database with PHP :S.

Here is my script

http://pastebin.org/68943

Thanks

Comment: No one is going to do your work for you/debug your entire program. Try breaking it down into the minimal set of code that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement that makes the insert you are checking for `opret` but the id in your input is `opret_besked` where as the name is `opret`.  With inputs the id overrides the name.  So change the name in your IF statement to `opret_besked` and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var opretform = $("#opret_besked").val;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tagwall.php",
    data: "opret_besked=" + opret_besked,
    success: function(response) {
            if(response == 1) {
                $("#response").append("Success!");
            } else {
                $("#response").append("Fejl.");
            }
    }
});
```

it insert the data in the database but the jquery animation dont work :/